# Difference between OpenWrt and OpenWISP

Tags: openwrt, openwisp

Recently, I configured OpenWrt on a lot of devices and it's a great firmware for wireless routers. I read a lot about OpenWISP which is:

> OpenWISP is a software platform designed to ease and automate the
>   management of networks, with a special focus on wireless networks,
>   mainly used in public wifi, mesh networks, community networks, and IoT
>   scenarios.
>
> OpenWISP 2, launched in December 2016, is the new generation of the
>   software which is gradually replacing OpenWISP 1 and aims to build an
>   ecosystem of applications and tools that make it easy for developers
>   to build custom networking applications in order to bring innovation
>   in the network infrastructure of communities that most need it.  [[Source]](http://openwisp.io/docs/general/values.html)

I think that it would play like an OpenWrt, however, I don't understand it completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenWISP is a web application composed with a collection of open source software tools, its aim is to allow the creation of customized network management solution, as well as to provide a default application which allows managing an OpenWRT based network.

Imagine it as a scriptable linux/python/django and web based system through which you can manage a fleet of OpenWRT devices.